# Document Set lookup error

Tags: list, lookup-column, document-set, library

I have what seems like a minor bug when setting up a new document set.

I've created a new content type based on a document set. One of the columns in the document set is a look up to a supplier list. So the user has to specify which supplier the document set pertains to. This is a required field.

However whenever I create a new document set of this content type and specify the supplier from the lookup and save it, the document set is created but the supplier is left blank.

I can go into the created document set and simply select it again and press save and it works, but the first time around it just ignores my initial selection.

Thanks